# Syncfusion controls not loading on iOS native UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin, uiwebview, syncfusion

I have a web application that built with ASP.NET MVC and used Syncfusion controls in it. Also, I am building iOS and Android application using native WebView.

The problem I am currently facing that Syncfusion controls are not working at iOS native UIWebView but it works fine at Android Webview and other Web browsers.

> [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't[1]')
>   getBrowserDetails (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2620892) setWidthToColumns
>   (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2713042)
>   _completeAction (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2705521) sendDataRenderingRequest (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2703872)
>   _renderGridContent (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2684094) render (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2674498)
>   _initGridRender (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2664775)
>   _checkDataBinding (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2631224)
>   _init (ej.web.all.min.js:10:2626321) (anonymous function) (ej.web.all.min.js:10:19759) (anonymous function)
>   (ej.web.all.min.js:10:20802) (anonymous function)
>   (actelion-test.pulselinks.com:995)

Above error is thrown only for the page which has SyncFusion control. Becuase of that error page failed to load the required scripts in the WebView and application not working as expected

My current Syncfusion script ej.web.all.min.js version is 14.2.

It would be very helpful if you let me know why I am getting above error and how can I resolve the error?

Thanks to advanced for your help.

Comment: I would report that problem to SyncFusion..  Personally, on iOS use a `WKWebView` instead of the `UIWebVIew`, not only is it 2x-4x faster due to the Nitro JS engine, it fully supports HTML5, gesture support, etc...

Comment: Great thanks for the comment. Have you reported that problem to SyncFusion? It would be very helpful if you let me know the steps to follow in order resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We could see you are facing some complexities while launching the Grid from Cordova browser in an IOS Platform. We can overcome this by changing the functionality of the getBrowserDetails as shown in the following code example.

```
<script>

    $(function () { 
        . ..  
        var getBrowsedtls = function () { 
            var b = navigator.userAgent.match(/(firefox|chrome|opera|msie|safari|ipad|iphone|ipod touch|android|)\s?\/?(\d+(.\d+)*)/i); 
            if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) 
                return { browser: "msie", version: $.uaMatch(navigator.userAgent).version }; 
            return { browser: b[1].toLowerCase(), version: b[2] }; 
        }; 
        $("#test").ejGrid({ 
            dataSource: values, 
         . . . . 
            showSummary: false, 
            load: function(args){ 
                this.getBrowserDetails = getBrowsedtls; 
            }, 
          .  . . 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

We have changed the method details in the load event of the Grid. Refer to the following API Reference.

https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#events:load